# Express.js and jsonplaceholder application

Tags: javascript, express.js

I have put together a small node application with **Express.js** and **[jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)**.

On the homepage, it displays posts by all users. You can also filter posts by one user (author).

In `app.js` I have:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var axios = require('axios');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

global.base_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
global.title = 'Express Magazine';

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

In `routes\index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const indexController = require('../controllers/index');
const router = express.Router();

// Get Posts
router.get('/', indexController.getHomepageData);

// Get Posts By User
router.get('/users/:uid/posts/', indexController.getPostsByUser);

// Redirect from bad routes
router.get('/users/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/users/:uid/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The `indexController` controler has the folwing code:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var helpers = require('../utils/helpers');

/* GET home page data */
exports.getHomepageData = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let [userData, postData] = await Promise.all([
            axios.get(`${base_url}/users`),
            axios.get(`${base_url}/posts`)
        ]);

        const users = userData.data;
        const posts = postData.data;

        res.render('index', {
            layout: 'layout',
            pageTitle: 'All posts',
            users: users,
            currentUser: null,
            posts: posts,

        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
};

/* GET posts by user */
exports.getPostsByUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let uid = req.params.uid;

        let [userData, currentUserData, postData] = await Promise.all([
            axios.get(`${base_url}/users`),
            axios.get(`${base_url}/users/${uid}`),
            axios.get(`${base_url}/posts?userId=${uid}`)
        ]);

        const users = userData.data;
        const currentUser = currentUserData.data;
        const posts = postData.data;

        res.render('index', {
            layout: 'layout',
            users: users,
            posts: posts,
            currentUser: currentUser,
            pageTitle: `Posts by ${currentUser.name}`,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
};
```

In the index.ejs view I use the above finctions. Sample:

```
<% if (posts) {%>
  <div class="row post-grid">
    <% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>
    <div class="col-sm-6 post">
      <div class="post-container">
        <h2 class="display-4 post-title"><%= post.title.toTitleCase() %></h2>
        <div class="short-desc">
          <%= post.body.capitalizeSentence() %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

The application works, but I am certain there is room for improvement.

##### Questions

1. Is the code DRY enough?
2. Is it missing anything *essential*?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to include the contents of `routes/users.js`? and is `helpers` actually used by the code in `indexController`? If so, what for?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I have added the required code.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ In fact, you can see the entire repo **[here](https://github.com/Ajax30/express-posts)**, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### *Is the code DRY enough?*

It does not seem very repetitive - looks fine to me.

One could be overly pedantic and suggest that the function inside the routes be abstracted:

> ```
> // Redirect from bad routes
> router.get('/users/', function(req, res) {
>     res.redirect('/');
> });
>
> router.get('/users/:uid/', function(req, res) {
>     res.redirect('/');
> });
> ```

to:

```
// Redirect from bad routes
const redirectToRoot = (req, res) => { res.redirect('/'); }
router.get('/users/', redirectToRoot);    
router.get('/users/:uid/', redirectToRoot);
```

but that may be excess work since it only appears twice. If the common function appears 3 or more times then abstracting is typically worth it.